# Replace multiple strings in one gsub() or chartr() statement in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub, character-replacement

I have a string variable containing alphabet `[a-z]`, space `[ ]`, and apostrophe `[']`, e.g. `x <- "a'b c"`
I want to replace apostrophe `[']` with blank `[]`, and replace space `[ ]` with underscore `[_]`.

```
x <- gsub("'", "", x)
x <- gsub(" ", "_", x)
```

It works absolutely, but when I have a lot of conditions, the code becomes ugly. Therefore, I want to use `chartr()`, but `chartr()` can't deal with blank, e.g.

```
x <- chartr("' ", "_", x) 
#Error in chartr("' ", "_", "a'b c") : 'old' is longer than 'new'
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: You've already solved it with the two gsubs. If it looks too ugly, you can create your own wrapper function that is "prettier" I suppose. But you can't use `chartr` because "blank" isn't a character, it's the lack of a character.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(".", list("'" = "", " " = "_"), x)
# [1] "ab_c"
```

Similarly, we can also use `mgsub` which allows multiple replacement with multiple pattern to search

```
mgsub::mgsub(x, c("'", " "), c("", "_"))
#[1] "ab_c"
```

Comment: How can I make it so I can call the old text inside the replacement text (for example, the ```do |word|``` action for regular gsub)?

Comment: @Guest2819 I don't think I understand. Better would be to create a new question showing example and expected output.

Answer (score 39):

I am a fan of the syntax that the `%<>%` and `%>%` opperators from the `magrittr` package provide.

```
library(magrittr)

x <- "a'b c"

x %<>%
  gsub("'", "", .) %>%
  gsub(" ", "_", .) 
x
##[1] "ab_c"
```

`gusbfn` is wonderful, but I like the chaining `%>%` allows.

Comment: what is the meaning of third argument "."  in gsub()

Comment: By default, the object on the left-hand-side of `%>%`  is *piped* to the first argument on the right-hand-side.  If the LHS needs to be, as in this example, the third argument, then the `.` is the placeholder.  See `vignette("magrittr")` for more details.

Answer (score 30):

I know it is a bit old but it is hard to pass on an efficient base R solution. Just use the pipe:

```
test <- "abcegdfk461mnb"
test2 <- gsub("e|4|6","",test)
print(test2)
```

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: @Brad - No it's not. This doesn't answer the question. OP asked to replace multiple strings with different replacements. The above only has a single replacement string for multiple patterns.

Comment: Good point, still nice bit of code. Many people didn't know you can declare multiple substrings in gsub using |

Answer (score 29):

I'd go with the quite fast function `stri_replace_all_fixed` from library([stringi](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi)):

```
library(stringi)    
stri_replace_all_fixed("a'b c", pattern = c("'", " "), replacement = c("", "_"), vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Here is a benchmark taking into account most of the other suggested solutions:

```
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)
library(gsubfn)
library(mgsub)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

x_gsubfn <-
x_mgsub <-
x_nested_gsub <-
x_magrittr <-
x_stringi <- "a'b c"

microbenchmark("gsubfn" = { gsubfn(".", list("'" = "", " " = "_"), x_gsubfn) },
               "mgsub" = { mgsub::mgsub(x_mgsub, c("'", " "), c("", "_")) },
               "nested_gsub" = { gsub("Find", "Replace", gsub("Find","Replace", x_nested_gsub)) },
               "magrittr" = { x_magrittr %<>% gsub("'", "", .) %>% gsub(" ", "_", .) },
               "stringi" = { stri_replace_all_fixed(x_stringi, pattern = c("'", " "), replacement = c("", "_"), vectorize_all = FALSE) }
               )
```

---

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
      gsubfn 458.217 482.3130 519.12820 513.3215 538.0100 715.371   100
       mgsub 180.521 200.8650 221.20423 216.0730 231.6755 460.587   100
 nested_gsub  14.615  15.9980  17.92178  17.7760  18.7630  40.687   100
    magrittr 113.765 133.7125 148.48202 142.9950 153.0680 296.261   100
     stringi   3.950   7.7030   8.41780   8.2960   9.0860  26.071   100
```

Answer (score 7):

I think nested gsub will do the job.

```r
gsub("Find","Replace",gsub("Find","Replace",X))
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use this technique: gsub third parameter is not a changeable object

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for a `magrittr` and/or `dplyr` solution, as well. However, I prefer not making a new copy of the object, especially if it is in a function and can be returned cheaply.

i.e.

```
return(
  catInTheHat %>% gsub('Thing1', 'Thing2', .) %>% gsub('Red Fish', 'Blue 
    Fish', .)
)
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("\\s", "", chartr("' ", " _", x)) # Use whitespace and then remove it
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this replace multi text character in column:

```
df$TYPE <- str_replace_all(df$TYPE, c("test" = "new_test", "G" = "N", "T" = "W"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function, which also allows omitting the argument for the replacement if the replacement is empty:

```
s=function(x,...,ignore.case=F,perl=F,fixed=F,useBytes=F){
  a=match.call(expand.dots=F)$...
  l=length(a)
  for(i in seq(1,l,2))x=gsub(a[[i]],if(i==l)""else a[[i+1]],x,ignore.case=ignore.case,perl=perl,fixed=fixed,useBytes=useBytes)
  x
}
```

```
> s("aa bb cc","aa","dd","bb")
[1] "dd  cc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error `'old' is longer than 'new'` because `'`  is length 2, and `_` is length 1. If you add another `_` to match with the white space and the length of `old`, then your code works:

```r
chartr("' ", "__", "a'b c")
#[1] "a_b_c"
```