# Replace multiple strings comprising of a different number of characters with one gsubfn()

Tags: r, metacharacters

Here [Replace multiple strings in one gsub() or chartr() statement in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r/33950268) it is explained to replace multiple strings of one character at in one statement with `gsubfn()`. E.g.:

```
x <- "doremi g-k"
gsubfn(".", list("-" = "_", " " = ""), x)
# "doremig_k"
```

I would however like to replace the string 'doremi' in the example with ''. This does not work:

```
x <- "doremi g-k"
gsubfn(".", list("-" = "_", "doremi" = ""), x)
# "doremi g_k"
```

I guess it is because of the fact that the string 'doremi' contains multiple characters and me using the metacharacter `.` in `gsubfn`. I have no idea what to replace it with - I must confess I find the use of metacharacters sometimes a bit difficult to udnerstand. Thus, is there a way for me to replace '-' and 'doremi' at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
gsubfn::gsubfn(pattern = "doremi|-", list("-" = "_", "doremi" = ""), x)
[1] " g_k"
```

The key is this search: `"doremi|-"` which tells to search for either `"doremi"` or `"-"`. Use `"|"` as the `or` operator.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to just use base R `sub` here:

```
x <- "doremi g-k"
result <- sub("doremi\\s+([^-]+)-([^-]+)", "\\1_\\2", x)
result

[1] "g_k"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a more generic solution to @RLave's solution -

```
toreplace <- list("-" = "_", "doremi" = "")
gsubfn(paste(names(toreplace),collapse="|"), toreplace, x)
[1] " g_k"
```