# How to substitute multiple characters in a string in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a string such like:

```
s <- "a bc de fg hij klmn 123 45 789"
```

And a vector of characters:

```
c <- c("a-b", "g-h", "j-k", "x-z", "y-5", "3-4")
```

what I wanted is substitute character such like `"a b"` in `s` with characters in c's `"a-b"`. A desired output would be:

```
new_s<-"a-bc de fg-hij-klmn 123-45 789"
```

Comment: I think this is something like this old question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/26171700 - a basic for loop running through each possibility should do it. `for (i in c) {s <- gsub(sub("-"," ", i), i, s)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple strings in one gsub() or chartr() statement in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A option is to use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\w\\s\\w", setNames(as.list(c), sapply(c, function(x) gsub("-", " ", x))), s)
#[1] "a-bc de fg-hij-klmn 123-45 789"
```

Explanation: We match `\\w\\s\\w` and replace them with patterns specified in the `list`

```
setNames(as.list(c), sapply(c, function(x) gsub("-", " ", x)))
#$`a b`
#[1] "a-b"
#
#$`g h`
#[1] "g-h"
#
#$`j k`
#[1] "j-k"
#
#$`x z`
#[1] "x-z"
#
#$`y 5`
#[1] "y-5"
#
#$`3 4`
#[1] "3-4"
```

---

Or even shorter (thanks to @Wen-Ben)

```
gsubfn("\\w\\s\\w", setNames(as.list(c), gsub("-", " ", c)), s)
```

Comment: `gsub('-', ' ', c)` could be `sub('-', ' ', c)` reducing the code by one character.