# Replace pattern in string with one regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace a suffix in a string. This suffix can be either `.x` or `.y`. If its is `.x` I want to replace it by `string1`(say) if it is `.y` it should be replaced by `string2`. (the replacement strings are arbitrary, but there is a clear mapping between suffix and replacement string, e.g. `.x -> .string1` and `.y -> .string2`).

I can easily achieve that by using *2* calls of `gsub` like this:

```
in_str <- c("a.x", "a.y")
gsub("\\.y$", ".string2", gsub("\\.x$", ".string1", in_str)))
# [1] "a.string1" "a.string2"
```

**Question**

Is there a `regex` with which I can achieve that with just *one*  call of `gsub`? Or is there any library function with which I can replace the suffixes in one go?

Comment: From a "clean code" perspective it would certainly be clearer to first split the string into prefix and suffix and the build the new string with an `if`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r/33950268) might be of interest.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for +1! For reference, code would look like this: `gsubfn("\\..$",list(".x" = ".string1", ".y"=".string2"), in_str)`

Comment: @ismirsehregal Would you mind to make it an answer, then I will accept it, otherwise I go for Ronak's solution.

Comment: @thothal If the link provides the answer to your question do you think it should be marked as duplicate of that question? Or you think these are different questions?

Comment: Yes indeed, I marked it as duplicate, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For those interested: I made benchmark regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178768/9841389) - A solution based on `library(stringi)` wins, which wasn't mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is what the regex' are for, I would do it differently:

```
in_str <- c("a.x", "a.y", "b.y", "b.x")
strmap <- c(.x="string1", .y="string2")
strmap[ gsub(".*(\\.[xy])$", "\\1", in_str) ]
```

Result:

```
       .x        .y        .y        .x 
"string1" "string2" "string2" "string1"
```

This has the advantage of being way more flexible and cleanly separating the definition of suffix mapping from the actual function that does the mapping. You can even automatize it more:

```
in_str <- c("a.x", "a.y", "b.y", "b.x")
strmap <- c(x="string1", y="string2")
suffixes <- paste0(names(strmap), collapse="")
pattern <- sprintf(".*\\.([%s])$", suffixes)
res <- strmap[ gsub(pattern, "\\1", in_str) ]
names(res) <- in_str
```

Result

```
      a.x       a.y       b.y       b.x 
"string1" "string2" "string2" "string1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not exactly what I am after, as I would like to replace just the suffix not the whole string, so the result should be `c("a.string1", "a.string2", "b.string1", b.string2")` in your example. I see how I could adapt your code to get that, but I guess in this case the 2 `gsub` are even easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mgsub` which accepts multiple patterns with multiple replacements

```
mgsub::mgsub(in_str, c("\\.x$", "\\.y$"), c(".string1", ".string2"))
#[1] "a.string1" "a.string2"
```