# How do I name file downloads in R using data from another column in dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of unique file IDs and links to download the files. It looks like this:

```
file_id <- c("id:fghjs12:ws8c7/syx", "id:f7gnsfu:7a6#*s", "id:dug:shxgcvu:6sh")
link <- c("https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp028.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp029.pdf", "https://www.dynare.org/wp-repo/dynarewp020.pdf")
df <- data.frame(file_id, link, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to download each file using the name of the handle. Some of the links are broken. So I have the following loop to do the task but it's not working..

```
download_documents <- function(url, file_id) {
   tryCatch(
     {download.file(url, paste0('~/Desktop/Dataset/files/', file_id))}, 
      error = function(e) {NA},
      warning = function(w) {NA})
}
Map(download_documents, df$link, df$file_id)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have a better solution? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: your code is fine it is the ids that are the problem as you cannot save a file with the following characters: \/:*?"<>| Can you create an id system without these characters?

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I could convert them all to any other character and keep the uniqueness of the IDs I think. Do you know how to do that? Would I use the gsub function maybe?

Comment: you could do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r but there is a remote possibility that you will end up with non-unique ids. Better to make new unique ids in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the `file_id` to valid names using `make.names`.

```
Map(download_documents, df$link, make.names(df$file_id))
```

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately when I use basename(url) to name the documents, there’s heaps of overlap (because it’s cutting everything off before the last ‘/‘) so files get overwritten.

Comment: @Oliver Do you mean the names of the file in `df$link` are not unique? Is there some specific way to name the files that you are looking for or any unique way is ok for you?

Comment: Yes, so because the basename function removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator, I am left with file names like 'dynarewp028.pdf' (using the example I posted). Some of the links are just 'file.pdf' because the last separator is right before the word 'file'. It would be fine if the name was the entire link but i can't figure out a way to do that. In any case, it's better to use the unique IDs I already have because they have a format that makes it easier to understand what they represent (e.g. the institution that had published the document, the year, etc.)

Comment: Ok..updated the answer to turn`file_id` to valid names. Can you check that?

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much!!