# Add symbols to data column in r

Tags: r

I have a data set that I'd like to add quote marks to based on three rules:

1. add quote marks before and after any =
2. add a quote mark after any ( and before any )
3. add a quote mark before and after any ,

For example

```
Input ->   (Ten + Four = Fourteen, Two - One = 1)
Output ->  "("Ten + Four"="Fourteen", "Two - One"="1")"
```

I must over-engineering this and was wondering if anyone had a good trick in base r?

Comment: gsub might be relevant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and nest it. Since you wanted `base` I did one nesting for you. For more elegant methods you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r)

```
foo <- c( "i = 2", "i , 2", " ( i 2 )")

#insert "="
foo2 <- gsub('=', '\"=\"', foo)
#insert ","
foo2 <- gsub(',', '\",\"', foo2) 
#insert "( and )"
foo2 <- gsub('\\)', '"\\)', foo2)
foo2 <- gsub('\\(', '\\("', foo2)

#same expression but nested.
foo2<- gsub('=', '\"=\"', gsub(',', '","', gsub('\\(', '\\("', gsub('\\)', '"\\)', foo))))
```

output:

```
cat(foo2)


i "=" 2   i "," 2    (" i 2 ")
```

---

amendment:

If you are putting your output through console you will get `\"` as output for `"`. This is basically the same. The console shows you the source code in this case.

```
'"' == '\"'
```