# Replace values in data.table using a key column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with 3 columns, V1, V2 and V3, for which I need to replace the values. The dataset has a fourth column, which contains all the possible values that can be in V1, V2 and V3, and a fifth column, which refers to the new value.

The original table looks like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | A |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 3 | C |

The desired end result would look like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | B | 1 | A |
| C | A | 4 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 4 | A | 3 | C |

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r/57178768#57178768) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698800/how-to-modify-a-variable-iteratively-using-data-table/70699096#70699096) related answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I would favor your translate column to be in the same dataset, nevertheless this would give you the right answer.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# select your columns of interest
cols <- 1:3

# create a named vector of your replacements
v <- dt$new_value
names(v) <- dt$value

# loop over the columns and replace values
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, str_replace_all, v), .SDcols = cols]
```

**results**

```
   V1 V2 V3 value new_value
1:  A  C  B     1         A
2:  C  A  4     2         B
3:  5  4  A     3         C
```

**data**

```
dt <- fread("V1 V2  V3  value   new_value
1   3   2   1   A
3   1   4   2   B
5   4   1   3   C")
```