# Automated tagging/text mining in excel

Tags: r, excel, text-mining

I have a monthly excel spreadsheet with the following:

| Category | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A | free text in paragraph form |
| B | free text in paragraph form |
| C | free text in paragraph form |
| B | free text in paragraph form |
| B | free text in paragraph form |
| A | free text in paragraph form |

I would like to add a third column that adds tags or keywords from a predetermined list that searches the free text and then pre-populates it based on whether one or more of the terms is found there or not.

So for example a list of tags could be price, distance, availability, location, and so on with the Keywords or Tags column populated based on the free text in the second column as below

| Category | Description | Keywords or Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Really doesn't like the price and location is too far | price, location |
| B | The distance is an issue and not too much availability | Distance, availability |
| C | Location is close so I like the convenience | location, convenience |
| B | The distance is near and there is a lot of availability | availability, distance |

As shown above, the tags would be separated by commas.

The issue is that the list of predetermined keywords is large (around 20 to 30 tags).

**My Questions:**

What would be the most efficient way to create this list without removing any tags?

Also, is there a way to do this in RStudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use regular expressions here to extract the keywords from the strings.

If we put the keywords in a vector `keywords`, we can use the `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package to extract all matching words in the string. I've made it into a simple function which we apply to the `Description` column of your data.frame, inserting the results into a new variable `Keys`

```
library(stringr)

get_tags <- function(str, tags) {
    res = str_extract_all(str,
                          regex(tags, ignore_case = T), # Search case insensitive
                          simplify = T)[,1] # Get result as vector, not matrix
    return(res[nchar(res) > 0])  # Drop empty strings from non-matched keywords
}

df$Keys <- sapply(df$Description,
                  function(x) paste0(get_tags(x, keywords),
                                     collapse=', ')) # Collapse matches w/ commas

df

  Category                                             Description                   Keys
1        A   Really doesn't like the price and location is too far        price, location
2        B  The distance is an issue and not too much availability distance, availability
3        C             Location is close so I like the convenience  Location, convenience
4        D The distance is near and there is a lot of availability distance, availability
```

Since you want the matches to be case insensitive, putting the regex pattern (`tags`) in the `regex` function allows us to specify that it should ignore case.

Comment: thanks for this! Is there a way I can substitute in one keyword if it finds another. For example, if the description says "location" it automatically uses the keyword "distance"?

Comment: With this approach, you could use a second set of regexes to [replace words in df$keys as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178768/8366499), though this might get unwieldily depending on how many substitutions you need.  If this is a central part of your goals, then you might want to make a lookup table of these matches and loop through it to generate keys. If so, you might want to ask a separate question and provide an [mcve] of the substations you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, which uses Excel formulas and avoids any external dependencies:

- use the `=SEARCH()` function in excel to find tags, populating a column for each keyword or tag
- Use `=TEXTJOIN()` to aggregate all tags

Example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category | Description | Tags (all) | price | location | Distance | availability |
| 2 | A | Really doesn't like the price and location is too far | '=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, D2:XX2) | '=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$1,$B2)), "", D$1) | ------ | ------ | ----> |

Output:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category | Description | Tags (all) | price | location | Distance | availability |
| 2 | A | Really doesn't like the price and location is too far | price, location | price | location |  |  |